# Query DSL not working in pyes search

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

I am trying to use a custom query DSL to get results using the pyes library. I have query DSL that works when I use the command line

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test_index/_search -d '{
    "query": {
       "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "field_value_factor": {
                "field": "starred",
                "modifier": "none",
                "factor": 2
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "types" : {
            "filters" : {
                "filters" : {
                    "category1" : { "type" : { "value" : "category1"}},
                    "category2" : {  "type" : { "value" : "category2"}},
                    "category3" : { "type" : { "value" : "category3"}},
                    "category4": { "type" : { "value" : "category4"}},
                    "category5" : { "type" : { "value" : "category5"}}
                }
            }, 
            "aggs": {
                "topFoundHits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 5
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

The idea here is to search across many categorized documents for all documents matching a particular string query. Then using aggregations I want to find the top five resulting documents by category. Starred items are boosted so that they show up above other search results.

This works great when I enter the command as listed above directly in terminal but it doesn't work when I try to put it in pyes. I'm not sure what the best way is to do it. The documentation for the pyes library is really confusing for me to translate this totally into pyes objects.

I'm trying to do the following:

```
 query_dsl = self.get_text_index_query_dsl()
 resulting_docs = conn.search(query=query_dsl)
```

(where `self.get_test_index_query_dsl` returns the query dsl dict above)

Searching as is gives me a:
`ElasticSearchException: QueryParsingException[[test_index] No query registered for [query]]; }]`

If I remove the parent "query" mapping and try:

```
query_dsl = {
   "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "starred",
            "modifier": "none",
            "factor": 2
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "types" : {
            "filters" : {
                "filters" : {
                    "category1" : { "type" : { "value" : "category1"}},
                    "category2" : {  "type" : { "value" : "category2"}},
                    "category3" : { "type" : { "value" : "category3"}},
                    "category4": { "type" : { "value" : "category4"}},
                    "category5" : { "type" : { "value" : "category5"}}
                }
            }, 
            "aggs": {
                "topFoundHits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 5
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This also errors out with: `ElasticSearchException: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT "aggs"]; }]`

These errors in addition to the fact that pyes doesn't seem to have a 'topFoundHits' functionality yet (I think) are holding me up.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it? 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I got this working using this library where you can just use your regular query dsl JSON syntax : http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.